# using opencv::cuda::demosaicing() without cuda sdk installed

Tags: c++, opencv

this is my make file,
from Cuda image processing module, I would like to use **demosaicing()**   
I'm am building cuda on my own. and do not want to use the cuda sdk
i'm using openCV 3.0.0 version

```
default:
    @echo Makefile targets are clean, build and rebuild

BUILD_DIR=build_dir

clean:
# Do nothing so that developers can do "clean" or "rebuild" solution without
# forcing to rebuild also OpenCV. Below is documented what the "clean" should do
# if it were to be enabled.
#   -rmdir /Q /S $(BUILD_DIR)

build: $(BUILD_DIR)\lib\$(CONFIGURATION)

rebuild: clean build

$(BUILD_DIR)\lib\$(CONFIGURATION): $(BUILD_DIR)\OpenCV.sln
    -cd $(BUILD_DIR)
    devenv OpenCV.sln /build "$(CONFIGURATION)|x64" /project ALL_BUILD
    devenv OpenCV.sln /build "$(CONFIGURATION)|x64" /project INSTALL

$(BUILD_DIR)\OpenCV.sln:
    if not exist $(BUILD_DIR) (mkdir $(BUILD_DIR) )
    cd $(BUILD_DIR)
    cmake                              \
    -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=FALSE         \
    -D BUILD_opencv_apps=FALSE         \
    -D BUILD_DOCS=FALSE                \
    -D BUILD_PACKAGE=FALSE             \
    -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=FALSE          \
    -D BUILD_TESTS=FALSE               \
    -D BUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB=FALSE        \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python2=FALSE      \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=FALSE      \
    -D BUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT=OFF       \
    -D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF                 \
    -D WITH_IPP=OFF                    \
    -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF                 \
    -D BUILD_CUDA_STUBS=ON             \
    -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64"   \
    $(SolutionDir)\3rdparty\opencv
```

the error i'm getting is

```
..opencv\modules\cudaimgproc\src\histogram.cpp(58): error C2244: 'histEven' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
```

Comment: If you're looking to just do debayering, the CPU implementation is [`cvtcolor`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) and pass the appropriate colour code such as `COLOR_BayerBG2BGR` etc.. If you're not planning to use CUDA then turn it off in your CMAKE

Comment: @EdChum great thanks, however if I want the exact same algorithm like matlab demosaic function?

Comment: I don't know what algorithm matlab uses but the openCV [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/demosaicing.cpp) is fully visible

Comment: @EdChum I meant to say that the matlab version and the cuda version are using the same implementation, that is why I wanted to cuda demosaic.

Comment: I would expect the CPU versions to be more feature rich (more capabilities) and that the CUDA implementations to be virtually the same as the CPU versions so there should be no difference, you can ask on openCV forum: http://answers.opencv.org/questions/ as the devs there will be able to answer definitively if the docs aren't clear